How to reuse a file object in jMeter beanshell
I am generating files of 10k to 100k records in single file by jMeter by using multiple beanshell samplers, file generation is very slow because in each sampler i am creating file with current timestamp and writing data into file and than closing the file.
For faster file writing i want to create single file object in first beanshell sampler and wanted to pass same object in other beanshell sampler to write their data. For this i am creating file object in beanshell sampler and setting file object in jMeter property with following manner and trying to reuse same object in other beanshell to write their data:
File file=new File(CompleteFilePath);
        props.put("file", file);

now trying to reuse file object in another beanshell sampler with
file = props.getObject("file");

and getting in jMeter response:

Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``file = props.getObject("file");"


There is no props.getObject() function, you need to use just props.get()
See Properties JavaDoc for more details
Also be informed that since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting so consider migrating.
More information: Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?
